# Robot_localization: Reason(s) not to post-process filter input data?

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just made a run with my assembly of gps/imu/BeagleBone Black on a vehicle platform.  While running the ekf filter, I performed a topic speed check on the /gps/filtered topic while recording a bagfile.  It turns out that doing so, greatly reduces the output from about 26 Hz to 5 Hz!  Must be out of bandwidth?

Can I pull the input data from the bagfile and rerun the filter through post-processing later?  Or is the sim time issue going to play into it?

Thanks as always,

B2256

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234375/robot_localization:-reason(s)-not-to-post-process-filter-input-data?/) by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2016-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If recording a bag file decreases your performance that much, then I don't think the issue is with `r_l`. I've run it on an Odroid U3 before at 75 Hz and never had the problem you're describing.

In any case, yes, you can just record the raw sensor data and run the EKF on the bagged data. The EKF doesn't know when it's running from a bag or from live data.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2016-05-23**:
That is what I had hoped. Thank you.